# Conditional Formatting Script to Change Font Size in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I'm trying to find a way to conditionally format the font size of the cell for Column A in a row, based on text found within the cell of Column B in the same row.

For example, if Column B in Row 2 contains "Most Wanted", then Column A in Row 2 should be font size 12, bold and underlined. (Normally it is plain text and size 10.)

It's pretty easy to change bold and underline formatting with the built-in conditional formatting but I can't find a way to change the font size as well.

Right now I'm using an adapted script I found and edited it to suit my needs.  But it changes the font for the entire row.  I'm not sure if there's something simple I need to edit or if I need an entirely new script.  I'm not great with scripts.  I was only able to edit the easy stuff.  Below is the adapted script I'm using now and here is an editable test sheet that it's currently attached to:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N4BT50HifwBS_qP4Tt6kxqwEOp2N-wVQxv7Jo2t0vQA/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Sets the row format depending on the value in the "Wanted Level" column.
function setRowColors() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var wantedlevelColumnOffset = getWantedlevelColumnOffset();

  for (var i = range.getRow(); i < range.getLastRow(); i++) {
    rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1);
    wantedlevel = rowRange.offset(0, wantedlevelColumnOffset).getValue();
    if (wantedlevel == 'Most Wanted') {
      rowRange.setFontSize('12').setFontWeight('bold').setFontLine('underline').clear;
    } else if (wantedlevel == 'Want') {
      rowRange.setFontSize('10').setFontWeight('bold').setFontLine('none');
    } else if (wantedlevel != 'Most Wanted' || 'Want') {
      rowRange.setFontSize('10').setFontWeight('normal').setFontLine('none');
    }
  }
}

//Returns the offset value of the column titled "Wanted Level"
//(eg, if the 7th column is labeled "Wanted Level", this function returns 6)
function getWantedlevelColumnOffset() {
  lastColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn);

  for (var i = 0; i < range.getLastColumn(); i++) {
    if (range.offset(0, i, 1, 1).getValue() == "Wanted Level") {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not the font -size- you can't.  At least not that I can find.

Comment: That's true. I'm sorry.

Comment: I hope they add it soon, though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `range.offset(...)` use something like `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1)`

Comment: That did the trick when i replaced `rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1);` with `rowRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1)`. Thank you!

Comment: A quick follow up question.  Ever since I added the script, the undo arrows and Ctrl Z don't work.  Is it possible that the script broke the undo feature somehow?

Comment: Oh, it's messing with Column A in my header rows.  How can i exclude them from effect? Thank you again! :)

Comment: Regarding the second comment, scripts should not break Ctrl Z. Regarding the third comment, check the start value of i, the first row is 1, so if you want to skip the header rows, you should use 2 instead.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not sure what is going on with the undo feature.  It works on all my other sheets but will not on this one.  In fact, when I delete the script, it works fine again. Give it a try in the test sheet I have linked in my original question.

Comment: Regarding the specific problem with undo, please post a new question.

Comment: As for the header being affected, it looks like any time I change an entry for Column B, all of Column A is processed (including Row 1) regardless of the row I'm making changes to.  So I need to exclude Row 1 from being processed all together but after looking for where i is defined, I can't quite figure out how to remove that from the range.  Thank you again.

Comment: I will post a new question for the undo problem. Thank you.

Comment: I still can't quite figure out how to ignore the header row in the script I'm using above. Any help would be fantastic.  Thank you.

Comment: I changed this line from `var i = range.getRow();` to `var i = 2;` to skip the first row.  It works to keep the header from being affected.  However, now the last row has no affect.  Am I missing something simple?  Thank you again for any help.

Comment: Change `i < range.getLastRow()` to `i <= range.getLastRow()`

Comment: Could you please help me again?  Sorry about this.  I am getting an error when applying this to my actual spreadsheet.  It works fine in the test sheet but when I run the script on my own sheet I get this error: `Cannot find method offset(number,(class)). (line 10, file "Code")`  Line 10 is: `wantedlevel = rowRange.offset(0, wantedlevelColumnOffset).getValue();`

Comment: I think I figured out the variable that is screwing this up.  I have multiple header rows.  "Wanted Level" is in row 5 and row 6 is yet another header row.  The actual data doesn't start until row 7.  I changed i = 7 but I'm not sure what else to change to compensate for the difference in header row layout.  I edited the test sheet with additional header rows for testing.  Thank you again!

Comment: I found it.  `getRange(x,1,1,lastColumn)` where x is the header row I need to point to.

Comment: If you have followup questions please post a new question.

Comment: Also you could ping me on chat.